# Create Virtual Directory to access shared network drive

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

I would like to create a virtual directory in my IIS application to be able to access from my web application to a shared directory.

My web server is on the A workstation and the directory share on B workstation.

From the file explorer of the A workstation I can access the shared directory of the B workstation but I can't when creating the virtual directory.

Let me explain:

### I create a virtual directory like this :

[image]

### but when i try to access to my directory :

[image]

I think this is because direct authentication is not configured on my server. So I followed [this microsoft tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308150/how-to-create-a-virtual-directory-on-an-existing-web-site-to-a-folder) but I block at this step:

> 8. On the User Name and Password page, type the user name and password that has sufficient privileges to gain access to the remote folder.

Because I can't figure out which user to choose.. If it is a user of workstation A or workstation B.

I've tried both but nothing works.

Do you have any idea why?

Thank you very much for reading and for your potential future response :D

Comment: The application pool identity right now is unable to access the remote file share. That's the cause of the current error page.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I can read on the internet, it is not possible without active directory ?

Comment: A production web app on IIS should use active directory somehow. If you insist to use without active directory, then the application pool identity must be a custom user account, and the same custom account must be created on the file share machine (with the same password).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it's clearer for me now.